# grub splash command freezing computer during resume from suspend (RAM)

Tags: grub2, 18.04, suspend, plymouth, resume

**Issue Description**
I have an issue resuming my computer if the splash command is present in the grub file under GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

Using fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
GPU is an Nvidia 1050 Ti.

With Nouveau driver enabled system will not resume from ram. The kernel crashes.

With Nvidia driver selected (either the one provided from Ubuntu or the latest from Nvidia which is 418.43 at time of writing this) the system will resume, but boot splash screen does not appear even with "splash" option enabled in Grub.

I've attempted many fixes found around this forum and the web with nothing working at all.

**Solution**
I solved this by switching to Kubuntu 18.04 LTS. Enabled Nvidia driver through driver manager application. I now can have splash screen and suspend to ram both enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by switching to Kubuntu 18.04 LTS. Enabled Nvidia driver through driver manager application. I now can have splash screen and suspend to ram both enabled.